The pullback of arrows into $1$ is the product of their domains, via representability of limits
Riehl's "Category Theory in Context" exercise 3.4.iv suggests proving that in any category $C$ with the terminal object $1$, the pullback $a \times_1 b$ of $a \to 1$ and $b \to 1$ is the product $a \times b$. She even suggests

to use the universal property of the [...] pullback to verify that the diagram $a \leftarrow a \times b \rightarrow b$ has the universal property that defines a product.

Indeed, it's straightforward to prove that directly as hinted, but I'd like to practice thinking in terms of representable universal properties of limits (since that's what the chapter is about, after all), so how about this alternative proof?
Consider any $x \in C$ and the representable functor $C(x, —)$. It preserves limits and their legs, hence $C(x, a \times_1 b) \cong C(x, a) \times_1 C(x, b)$ is the pullback of $C(x, a) \to 1$ and $C(x, b) \to 1$ (here I also used that $C(x, 1) \cong 1$). We know what a pullback in $\text{Set}$ is, so it's easy to see that here it really is a product: $C(x, a) \times_1 C(x, b) = C(x, a) \times C(x, b)$.
Now, since this holds for every $x$, it also holds in the functor category $Set^{ob C^{op}}$ and thus in $Set^{C^{op}}$. Hence the Yoneda embedding of $a \times_1 b$ is the limit of the product diagram, hence, since Yoneda reflects limits, $a \times_1 b$ is the product too.
Does that make sense, or was I too optimistic and omitted some details somewhere?
